# Wrapping workspaces in Cinnamon environment

Tags: workspaces, cinnamon, workspace-switcher

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with the Cinnamon environment. I'm wondering if it's possible to make it so I can wrap workspace switching (so when I reach the last workspace, shifting right again will bring me to the first workspace). This would be far less tedious...

Edit as per terdon's observing: my Cinnamon version is 2.0.14

Comment: Which version of Cinnamon? You can find out by running `cinnamon --version`.

Comment: version 2.0.14. Whoops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So go to `system settings` > `workspaces` and activate **"Allow cycling through workspaces"**

[image]

If you don't see that option, you may have to click on the "Switch to Advanced Mode" button on the lower left (the one that says "Switch to Normal Mode" in the screenshot above).